# Set SQL Server Database to only allow ANSI Compliant SQL Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

Is there a way that I can force my sql server database to only use SQL Compliant code?

This way the SQL Code is easy transportable to other Database systems like Oracle, IBM and other ANSI Compliant systems.

Or other viable approach to get the same result?

Comment: There's no such thing like ANSI Compliant SQL Code. There are conformance levels to the various standards (SQL92, 99, 2003,2006,2008,2011) and no database conforms fully to all of them. In fact, the systems you mentioned are some of the worst offenders.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? There *are* defaults that result in non-standard behaviour if you modify them, eg setting ANSI_NULLS to off. In other cases, the standards are (intentionally) vague enough to allow vendors to implement whatever they want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am building soome SQL Stored procedures that will be triggered by a front end application. However I want these Stored Procedures so generic that they will run on various rdbms without changes. this would be the ideal scenario.

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong technology. Stored procedures or [SQL/PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM) are the least standardized. Each of the products you mentioned has its own   [procedural extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Procedural_extensions). *Why* are you looking for generic procedures instead of using an ORM?

Comment: I have 2 reasons, where only one of them is a valid one. I am not acquainted with ORM. Second the logic will be more complex than CRUD manipulations and will also be on large datasets. I suppose that SQL code is more powerful on the DB engine than ORM. Thank you already for your input.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, not really.

However, it doesn't really make much of a difference - the idea that you could use the same (ANSI or otherwise) SQL accross widely different SQL engines is just an illusion. The usual approach nowadays is to use someone who builds the queries for you - at least that allows some optimizations before sending the SQL off. You can even have different database structures if that's important.

Even the data types and their representations may differ between different database clients. Right now, for example, I'm working on a legacy Oracle application which uses DataSets. On Oracle, all `number`s are `decimal`s in C#. On MS SQL, some are `decimal`s, some are `int`s. Even using purely ANSI SQL, you need to handle tiny incompatibilities like this, and it's very hard to chase performance as well.

For example, some Oracle queries in the legacy application use explicit indices - it really is necessary thanks to the (bad) way the queries are built and formed, but only on Oracle - MS SQL doesn't seem to require them at all. There's SQLs that are better taken care of by the MS SQL execution planner than the Oracle one and vice versa - some of the performance critical queries look completely different on the two engines. And it would help performance *a lot* if I could have different DB structures for each of those. And there's different paradigms of development as well - Oracle code requests IDs prior to inserts (etc.), while the standard on MS SQL is to let the DB engine handle that - you just make sure the associations on code side are properly translated over to the relational fields on the DB side.

And that's just two major DB engines. MySQL, Postgres, DB2... all of them have tiny quirks, even in full-ANSI mode. Add to that the fact that ANSI standards aren't even fully implemented in *any* of those, and the bubble bursts easily.

Even using an intermediate (like some O/RM system) will expose lots of leaks. The key is to keep as far away from anything specific as long as you can - and make sure everyone is well aware of the places where you can't keep up with the charade.

Comment: Someone should first define what "ANSI Compliant" means and what level of conformance are we talking about. **NO database** is fully compliant with in all conformance levels, even for the SQL92 standard

Comment: I agree with the first line. However, I'd suggest that any engine that does not implement "SQL:86" or ANSI SQL in a standards compliant fashion cannot really be called an SQL engine.

Comment: @Jodrell Sure. But that's just a tiny part of the whole picture. Just understanding the syntax and applying it without ambiguities is the easy part (and even that isn't done 100%). Making sure it actually works well, that's the hard part. ANSI SQL is great, but only in the small things like making `case` work the same on MS SQL and Oracle, so that you don't have to translate `decode` to `case` etc. It does *not* mean you can just write the same SQL for all the DBs. Abstractions will always leak. ANSI SQL leaks quite a bit :D

Comment: @Jodrell ORDER BY was made legal in 2008, yet all products support it since ... well, I can't remember that far. All the major databases used non-standard extensions at one point or another. I'm sure if you check SQL86 you'll find exceptions in all - unless SQL86 was superseded to make the most common extensions legal.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `order by` was everywhere, true. But it works slightly different everywhere too. Not in the simplest queries, of course. But add sub-queries, grouping, unions, windowing functions... They all have their small differences.

Comment: It could be worse. All vendors tried to force the standard to adapt to their implementations, to the point that IBM wanted to enforce `5=X` in `WHERE`, because it run faster back then. Wait it *is worse* - three-valued logic (nulls) was never fixed!